# define an output schema for a nested json in langchain

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

Whats the recommended way to define an output schema for a nested json, the method I use doesn't feel ideal.

```
# adding to planner -> from langchain.experimental.plan_and_execute import load_chat_planner

refinement_response_schemas = [
        ResponseSchema(name="plan", description="""{'1': {'step': '','tools': [],'data_sources': [],'sub_steps_needed': bool},
 '2': {'step': '','tools': [<empty list>],'data_sources': [<>], 'sub_steps_needed': bool},}"""),] #define json schema in description, works but doesn't feel proper
    
refinement_output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(refinement_response_schemas)
refinement_format_instructions = refinement_output_parser.get_format_instructions()

refinement_output_parser.parse(output)
```

gives:

```
{'plan': {'1': {'step': 'Identify the top 5 strikers in La Liga',
   'tools': [],
   'data_sources': ['sports websites', 'official league statistics'],
   'sub_steps_needed': False},
  '2': {'step': 'Identify the top 5 strikers in the Premier League',
   'tools': [],
   'data_sources': ['sports websites', 'official league statistics'],
   'sub_steps_needed': False},
    ...
  '6': {'step': 'Given the above steps taken, please respond to the users original question',
   'tools': [],
   'data_sources': [],
   'sub_steps_needed': False}}}
```

it works but I want to know if theres a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can see the recommended approach is to use the pydantic output parser as opposed to the structured output parser... [python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/output_parsers](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/output_parsers/pydantic)/… (and dealing with nesting explained here... [youtube.com/watch?v=yD_oDTeObJY](https://youtube.com/watch?v=yD_oDTeObJY)).

e.g.

```
from langchain.output_parsers import PydanticOutputParser
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator
from typing import List, Optional

...

class PlanItem(BaseModel):
    step: str
    tools: Optional[str] = []
    data_sources: Optional[str] = []
    sub_steps_needed: str

class Plan(BaseModel):
    plan: List[PlanItem]


parser = PydanticOutputParser(pydantic_object=Plan)
parser.get_format_instructions()
```